# Run ansible task when host in group which contain string

Tags: ansible

I have a host which contain in some groups

```
ok: [domain.examle.com] => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "group_names": [
            "abc",
            "abc_b",
            "abc_b_p",
            "abc_b_p_mn",
            "abc_b_p_shd"
        ]
    },
    "changed": false
}
```

I need a condition which will allow me to run task when host is in group which have '_shd' or '_mn'

I tried using `when: "'_shd' in group_names"` but it works only when i use full group name

Comment: => `when: group_names | select('regex', '^.*_(shd|mm)$') | count > 0`

Comment: I think this is what i need but i see an error ```msg": "blablabla object of type 'generator' has no len blablabla```. When i print var with ```group_names | select('regex', '^.*_(shd|mm)$')``` result is ```"<generator object do_map at 0x7f82e60105f0>"```

Comment: You are using ansible < 2.10. Please upgrade to a still supported version (>=2.12). As a workaround, you can add the `| list` filter in between the `select` and `count` filters to make this compatible with your outdated version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was provided in the question comments:

`when: group_names | select('regex', '^.*_(shd|mm)$') | count > 0` for > 2.10 versions

`when: group_names | select('regex', '^.*_(shd|mm)$') | list | count > 0` for < 2.10 versions

Answer (score 0):

I dont see why your when dont work, are you looping your list and evaluating every value?
This example bellow works fine. So maybe the issue is you are trying to evaluate the full list at once? as a single value?

```yaml
---
  - hosts: localhost
    gather_facts: no
    vars:
      - text: adasasdas_shd
    tasks:
      - name: probar texto
        debug:
          msg: "Contain text"
        when: '"_shd" in text'
```

With loop:

```yaml
---
  - hosts: localhost
    gather_facts: no
    vars:
      - text: [adasasdas_shd, popoopo, asdadsa]
    tasks:
      - name: Test list
        debug:
          msg: "Contains text"
        when: '"_shd" in item'
        loop: "{{text}}"
```

Using Join filter ( My favorite)

```lua
---
  - hosts: localhost
    gather_facts: no
    vars:
      - text: [adasasdas_shd, popoopo, asdadsa]
    tasks:
      - name: Test list
        debug:
          msg: "Contains text"
        when: '"_shd" in text |join'
```

Comment: I think that i expressed my mind unclear but group_names is magick variable. It's an array of strings

Comment: @Po_temkin, This example explains in a generic way how to achieve your goal, I also don't see why your `when: "'_shd' in group_names"` should not work. I wasn't able reproduce an issue.